# avoiding small heap allocations on c#

Tags: c#, arrays, memory-management, bridge.net

I am currently doing code C# code with Bridge.Net compiler that works a lot with points, lines and boxes which means that I deal often with pairs or quads of ints or floats.

I am wondering, what's the best way in C# to represent them?

-I do not want to use tuples because I want to be able to loop over the context. I don't think I can use any advanced reflection tricks for that since I'm compiling to Javascript and even if I can they are not worth it.

-Defining my own structs for something this common seems an absurdly code-heavy solution.

-I don't want `unsafe`, so `fixed` and `stackalloc` keywords are out of question.

Currently, I just use reqular arrays, like this:

```
//calculates meeting point of two lines
public static int[] MeetingPoint(int[,] a, int[,] b)
{   //...
}
```

but that means a lot of heap allocations, often in often-used low-level code. Seems wasteful to me. In C/C++/D I would use static arrays but in C# there's no such thing unless going `unsafe`.

The question is, Is there some library type for this, preferably in the standard library? Or do I just have to design some big preallocated arrays which would store my small data pieces in bulks?

EDIT: Big arrays would anyway be a bad solution since they still would be at heap even when being handled.

Comment: heap allocations are, generally, *cheap*. Until you've *profiled* code and isolated the *actual* hotspots, don't assume you'll be able to guess where the bottlenecks actually are.

Comment: That's true. But I think I still should design my code so that I can change it to do the calculations on stack if that proves to be the bottleneck, without a major redesign. How would I ensure that?

Comment: I don't quite understand how your question relates to Bridge.NET. Is your C# code supposed to be working separately, like a regular .NET application?

P.S. As for Bridge.NET - you might be interested in looking at Sequence type. It works similarly to Tuple, but provides AsArray() method allowing iteration through items: https://github.com/bridgedotnet/Bridge/issues/2200

Comment: Just mentioned that i use it to compile my c# to Javascript. But that sequence type looks promising, I'll check it out. Thanks.